# call Jquery function from javascript using API

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I call a jQuery function from JavaScript?

```
//jQuery
$(function() {

    function my_func(){
           /.. some operations ../
    } 
});

//JavaScript
function js_func () {

   my_func(); //== call JQuery function 
}
```

Comment: `jQuery` is `JavaScript` library, what you are asking ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345722/calling-jquery-function-from-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend your function to jquery, then use it with $

```
    $.extend({
        my_jsFunc: function() {
            console.log('============ Hello ============');
        }
    });

    $(function(){
        $.my_jsFunc();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure y do you need this anyway here's a simple example...

```
$(function(){
    $('#my_button').click(function(){
       alert("buttonClicked");   //Jquery    
    });
});    

function my_func(){
    $('#my_button').click();  //JavaScript    
}
```

//HTML

```
<button id="my_button" onclick="my_func();"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are asking the wrong question but I think what you are searching for is:

```
$.my_func();
```

Answer (score 0):

the my_func() is just normal function so should be kept outside jquery Dom ready function

```
$(function() {
    my_func();

});

 // This function should be outside from jquery function
  function my_func(){
       /.. some operations ../
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    function my_func(){
       /.. some operations ../
    }
})
```

runs the everything inside when the page is "ready".

You don't need that.

Just define the function list this

```
function my_func(){
   /.. some operations ../
}
```

P.S. "How can i call a jQuery function from JavaScript?" is a bad question. jQuery is a library written using Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by actually changing the declaration to outside jQuery callback, but if you have some specific purpose following will work for you

```
$(function() {

    window.my_func = function() {
           /.. some operations ../
    } 
});

//JavaScript
function js_func () {

   my_func(); //== call JQuery function 
}
```