# Trigger a jQuery function from another file in JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

How I can call/trigger a jQuery function (which is in another file) from JS.
So basically this is the jQuery function (/js/animation.js).

```
$('#spin').click(function () {
    var tickets = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + 1;
    if(tickets < 51) {  
    var winner = 155;
    }
    else {
    var winner = 145;   
    }
    rouletteSpin(winner);
});
```

I know that its based on a codepen Roulette Animation.
Now the problem is that it should not roll without going through an if statement.
The statement should be a variable using Database info.
That's the point.
In my opinion you cant use PHP / select DB Info in jQuery so I decided to go into my index.php to trigger the jQuery function after the if statement in js went through.
So let me show you my HTML Button + JS Function:

```
 onclick="openCase()
```

into the first HTML Button tag.

Now the JS Function:

```
    <script>    
    var credits = CodeToGet_MYSQL_DB_Info_here_written_in_php;


    function openCase() {
    if(credits > 10000) {
     spinIt();
    }
    else {
        alert('Something went wrong');
    }
    }
```

And changed the jQuery Function (in path /js/animation.js) to the following:

```
function spinIt () {
    var tickets = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + 1;
    if(tickets < 51) {  
    var winner = 155;
    }
    else {
    var winner = 145;   
    }
    rouletteSpin(winner);
});
```

That is not working. I already googled a lot so please don't flame me.
Already used pretty much every method of this post:

[calling Jquery function from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345722/calling-jquery-function-from-javascript)

Would be nice if someone can help me out!

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: load the js file first which call the function then the second which have the actual function.

Comment: *"In my opinion you cant use PHP / select DB Info in jQuery"* Yes you can, by using AJAX.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Read the whole text and you should understand my question.
"How can I call a jQery function (which is in another file) in JS?"

Comment: Read it. Edited it. Nope, still don't understand the question and others agree with me.

Comment: Can you add the code that you are using to retrieve the information from the database? I would start debugging there, make sure that `credits` is actually returning a result as expected and not an undefined variable.